# Fix last n commits to previous commit automatically

Tags: bash, git

I often find myself doing rebase manually in an interactive form in a way as follows. Say I want to squash two last commit to third commit.

First I execute:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now editor pops up, I mark two last commits as fixup. I close the editor and then rebasing is done (if there are no errors). I'd like to automate this by executing a script with a parameter that gives a number of commits, i.e. when 2 is given as parameter, last two commits are fixup to third commit. Please see an example:

> some other commits...
>
> add nice feature
>
> fix 1
>
> fix 2

In that scenario I'd like `add nice feature` to incorporate changes from `fix 1` and `fix 2`, and I like to `fix 1` and `fix 2` not be present at all.

I wrote a bash script that does what I want. It works seems to work fine.

**UPDATE**

In this review, I'm most interested in knowing whether my approach to git is a proper one, especially if it doesn't break anything during rebasing.

```
fixup() {
  local no_of_commits="$1"
  if [ -z "$no_of_commits" ]; then
    echo "You must provide a number of commits to fixup!"
    return 1
  elif ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "$no_of_commits is not a number!"
    return 2
  fi

  #git stash save

  git reset --soft "HEAD~$(no_of_commits)" &&
    git add --all &&
    git commit --fixup "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" &&
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase --interactive --autosquash --no-fork-point "$(git rev-parse HEAD~2)" &&
    echo "Rebased $(no_of_commits) succesfully!"

  #git stash pop
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `[[` consistently instead of `[`.  It will help you avoid surprises like variables ending up empty.  In your case quoting the variable takes care of it, but `[[` is still a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Syntax errors

The posted code has some syntax errors:

> ```
>   git reset --soft "HEAD~$(no_of_commits)" &&
>     git add --all &&
>     git commit --fixup "$(git rev-parse HEAD)" &&
>     GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase --interactive --autosquash --no-fork-point "$(git rev-parse HEAD~2)" &&
>     echo "Rebased $(no_of_commits) succesfully!"
> ```

That is, all the `$(no_of_commits)` must really be `$no_of_commits` or `${no_of_commits}` if you like.

#### Use `git commit --amend`

`git commit --fixup` is useful when you will have a bunch of fixup commits in the midst of other commits. To squash together the last N commits, is a special case, and can be done simpler using `git reset ... && git commit --amend`:

```
  git reset --soft "HEAD~$no_of_commits" &&
    git commit --amend -C HEAD
    echo "Rebased $no_of_commits successfully!"
```

I also dropped the `git add --all` in the middle, because it's not necessary for the purpose you described, in fact it may have unintended effects.
That is, any uncommitted changes will get added. If I want to fixup the last N commits, I would want "just that", and nothing else. If I wanted the uncommitted changes included, I would commit them.

#### Use more functions

I would extract the conditional that checks if `$no_of_commits` is a number to its own function.
Then you could easily copy-paste and reuse in other scripts.

Also, the `elif` should use `$no_of_commits` instead of `$1`.

#### About rebasing...

> In this review, I'm most interested in knowing whether my approach to git is a proper one, especially if it doesn't break anything during rebasing.

Collapsing the last N commits isn't really *rebasing*, because no commits are applied on top of some other commit, it's really just *amending* a commit.

As mentioned in the previous section, I think the `git add --all` operation is a mistake, which I would consider a defect of the otherwise nice functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages should go to standard error, rather than standard output:

```
  if [ -z "$no_of_commits" ]; then
    echo "You must provide a number of commits to fixup!" >&2
    return 1                                              ### HERE
```

I don't think there's a good case for returning distinct error codes for missing argument and invalid argument.  Are you ever going to make use of the different status values?

Comment: No, I'm not. One return value will suffice.